# How can I rename PDFs from Selenium downloads (Python) as I'm downloading them to avoid rewriting PDFs with identical names?

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So, I am using selenium to automate google searches and I'm using it to download any PDFs that are found via my google search. Below is my code, but I'm thinking about the download scheme. It's not as robust as I'd like it to be because it will rewrite any files that have the same name. I'm wondering if there's a simple method to download the contents of any found PDFs and use my own naming convention which possibly uses my keywords or even the iterator of my loop to control the naming.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import JavascriptException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd


###if chromedriver doesn't have permissions then navigate to folder where chromedriver is and
### allow permissions by running this in the terminal (MacOS):
# $ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver 


 a = [
 "Curriculum Review",
 "annual update",
 "memorandum of understanding",
 "cirriculum map",
]

 b = [
     
 "Pepperdine University",
"Harvard University",
"Yale University"
 ] 

 c = [
 "mathematics"
 ]

keys = []

 for x,y,z in [(x,y,z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]:
     keys.append(z +" "+ x +" "+ y)

links_list = []


path_to_driver = r"/..../chromedriver"
download_dir = r"/.../pdf_dump"

'''these lines below set the options to hide the application, allows chrome to work in the background and
ignore any certificate errors that may arise, then it sends the commands and tells it to download
into the download path we set in our directory

the for loop waits 10 seconds (decent load time for any OS), loads google, waits another 5,
sends in the query (our lists we passed a+b+c) then moves down 1 (our first search result) and searches
for a pdf, counts down for us and tells us whether the pdf exists or not, downloads (or not) then moves
onto the next query we want to pass into google, no matter if a pdf exists or if there's no 
search result...
'''

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": download_dir,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
})
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_driver, options=chrome_options)
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)

for k, key in enumerate(keys):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

        sleep_between_interactions = 5
        searchbar = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        searchbar.send_keys(key)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        searchbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        pdf_element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ("//a[contains(@href, '.pdf')]"))
        key_index_number = str(keys.index(key) +1 )
        key_length = str(len(keys))
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + key_length)
            
        if len(pdf_element) > 0 and  key_length < key_index_number :
            print("pdf found for: "+ key)
            pdf_element[0].click()
            time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            print("downloaded " + key_index_number + " out of "+ str(len(keys)))
                
        elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and key_index_number != key_length:
            print("pdf NOT found for "+ key)
            print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")  
            
            
 
            
            try:
                google_search = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={key}"
                driver.get(google_search)
                clicked_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//h3)[1]/../../a').click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(10)

            except JavascriptException:
                continue
                html_source_code = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
                html_soup: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')
                links_list = [html_soup for potato in html_soup.find_all('a')]
                
            
        elif len(pdf_element) == 0 and str(keys.index(key)) == str(len(keys)):
            print('Empty')
            
    except IndexError as index_error:
        print("Couldn't find pdf file for "+"\"" + key + "\""+" due to Index Error moving on....")
        print(key_index_number + " out of " + str(len(keys)))
        continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("search bar didn't load, iterating next in loop")
        print(" pdf NOT found for "+ key)
        print(key + " pdf not downloaded, moving on...")
        continue
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        print("element either didn't load or doesn't exist")
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        continue
```

So, ideally, it'll download either with names like `key_iterative.pdf` or even `{name} + iterative.pdf` or something like that. I was considering using an if statement to check if `pdf_element == existing_file` or something like that and use that to determine the name, or even somehow circumvent the check and just come in with my own custom names possibly something like `key+key_index_number.pdf` so the names can be derived from my code but I'm just not sure how to move forward.

Comment: I attempted to use something like this:
```os.rename(pdf_element,str(key)+str(key_index_number)+'.pdf')```
within the first if statement but I'm getting an error:
```os.rename(pdf_element,str(k)+str(key_index_number)+'.pdf')
TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list```

not sure why it's not being registered as an individual string.

Comment: nope, you're incorrect. The first "if" actually does work. Also, curious as to how this helps solve the issue pertaining to the post?